# Remove Vertical Scroll on iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe

Having some trouble removing the vertical scroll from the Available Careers listing iframe on this sample page.

If I increase the height="1600px" to height="1700px", then the vertical scroll disappears on desktop, but still remains on mobile.

```
    <div class="jobs__wrap bg-grey-pattern">
    <div class="jobs__header">
    <h4>Available Careers</h4>
    </div>
    <iframe src="https://demorecruiting.paylocity.com/recruiting/jobs/All/85e4f102-5f4c-4548- 
    b6ca-cc391c862dc5/CPUMMILL" width="100%" height="1600px" style="border:0;" 
    allowfullscreen="no" loading="lazy"></iframe>
    </div>
```

And the tricky thing is that currently there are 16 open available job positions.
That number will fluctuate, and the iframe section could show as little as 2 or 3 or as many as 20 or so available positions...so the iframe job listing section height will decrease and increase.

Comment: Unless that other site offers you some active help (i.e., send its document's current dimensions to the parent page using `postMessage` or something similar), there is little you can do.

Comment: Do you have access to the iframe content, or is this a 3rd party iframe? If you could implement some code inside the iframe, maybe the iFrame Resizer http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/ would be a solution?

Comment: The only content we have access to if posting the job listings, border color, and logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
 <div class="jobs__wrap bg-grey-pattern">
    <div class="jobs__header">
    <h4>Available Careers</h4>
    </div>
    <iframe onload="resizeIframe(this)" id="iframe-id" src="https://demorecruiting.paylocity.com/recruiting/jobs/All/85e4f102-5f4c-4548- 
    b6ca-cc391c862dc5/CPUMMILL" width="100%" height="100%" style="border:0;" 
    allowfullscreen="no" loading="lazy"></iframe>
    </div>
<script>

  function resizeIframe(iframe) {
    iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
  }

</script>
```

Comment: I tried using the above code along with the iframe script, but unfortunately this did not work.

Comment: Did You Use "Onload Function" in iFrame Tag?

Comment: Zahar I did... Script added to functions.php and copy/pasted the iframe code as you have it written. Now that section of the Careers page shows error about job posting not being listed. Strange because I still see the "Powered by Paylocity" and that is where the jobs are coming from. So....I updated the Paylocity URL with the live job posting URL and everything looks good now on desktop, mobile still has a scroll and firefox. Strange because the sample Paylocity URL still shows job listings, but not when used in the mentioned iframe. Anyways....looks like this works. Thank you very much! –

Comment: Thankyou | Kinldy Mark My Answer as a Correct Answer.